# How to remove all Mach-O executables in a directory via Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

Let's say I put all my C codes and the executables in `~/anta40/Codes/C`.

Removing all the C codes via Terminal is easy:

```
rm *.c
```

My question is how to remove all Mach-O executables (from compiling the C codes). On Windows this is very easy, because executables usually have `exe` extension, so you simply do:

```
del *.exe
```

I think this is trickier on MacOS because the executables typically don't have specific extension. `file` may be useful, e.g:

```
$ file sortdemo
sortdemo: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

No idea about the rest.

Comment: The extension does not tell you anything. You can also not conclude from the extension .c, that this must be a C source file. In your case, I would loop over all files, apply the `file` command (which, BTW, isn't 100% foolproof either), and remove the file if `file` believes that it is a Mach-O executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no filenames with whitespace or other „funny“ characters, something like

```
rm -i $(file * | grep Mach-O | cut -d : -f 1)
```

should do the trick.

PS: `rm -i` will prompt you for each file. If you are sure that only the correct files get selected you can remove the `-i`.

Comment: Will that handle filenames containing whitespace?

Comment: @gidds No, it will not. But folks using whitespace in the name of unix binaries are way braver than I will ever be :-)

Comment: You might be surprised… A search of my `/Applications` folder finds 108 Mach-O executables with a space in the filename. (That's just checking the basename, excluding loads more in directories with spaces.) Some are quite obscure, but not all — e.g. `Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`. In any case, it's well worth being aware of the limitation.

Comment: @nohillside thank you. It works. Downside: it also remove object files. Well, fine with me. Now my source directory is clean from any binary file.

Comment: @gidds I'm OK with such limitation. I never use space for naming my source files. And this is only for "cleaning" my source code directories, and not a general purpose tool.

Comment: @anta40 Maybe grep for `'Mach-O 64-bit executable'` then, or whatever is different between executables and .o files.

Answer (score 1):

As this is specifically about C code and the executables derived therefrom, I just want to add that usually this is handled by your build tool.

One of the most popular build tools for C code is the `make` program. Commonly you would write the command `make` to create the executables, and `make clean` to remove them and other generated files afterwards.

So instead of manually deleting Mach-O files (which might in some cases delete more or less than what you wanted), I would recommend using a build tool.

Comment: One still needs to define the `clean` rule in the Makefile though.

Comment: Of course. You would never do it by searching for Mach-O files though.

Comment: Sure, might be worth adding a sample rule though. For bigger projects I probably would even use a dedicated build directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, for all my smaller C codes (usually for testing ideas), I don't use Makefiles. Simply invoke `gcc` or `clang` :/